# Using Z-index and positioning text in absolute divs to create a water-mark

Tags: html, css, position, z-index, absolute

I'm making a div that I want to say "Banner" with a larger "BANNER" in grey behind it. Kind of like a water-mark. But the positioning is wrong and the browser is rendering the 'water-mark' on top of the banner text.

```css
.banner {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.foreground {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 7em;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div style="position:absolute; width:100%">
      <p class="foreground">Banner!</p>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; width:100%">
      <p class="background">BANNER!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For reasons I don't want to go into here, `banner` needs to keep it's `position: absolute` (Sorry if that's too restrictive)

Otherwise we're free to play around with it. I would like the water mark to be slightly overflowing from the top and bottom of the `banner` div or at least flush with the top.

But **most importantly** I need the water-mark **behind** the `foreground` divs content.

Thank for any help! I prefer a CSS solution but JS would be appreciated too. PS [here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyhupL9r/) if you prefer that.

**EDIT** I fixed the height issue by putting `margin-top:-5%` which I tried before, but with a percentage WAY too high. Apparently it goes of the height of the page not it's parent. Perhaps because it's `position:absolute`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: "For reasons I don't want to go into here, banner needs to keep it's position: absolute" ummmm.... change that to relative and you're good.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, it would cause more problems then it's worth. Any ideas on pushing the text up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to appear in a different order, change the order of your html. You can then also get rid of the z-indexes. So:

```
<div class="banner">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div style="position:absolute; width:100%">
   <p class="background">BANNER!</p>
  </div>
  <div style="position:absolute; width:100%">
   <p class="foreground">Banner!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively / additionally:
If you need it to be a watermark, why not add some opacity of like 0.3 to .background? That does not actually put it behind the text, but makes it appear like a watermark.

Working in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0srj5hus/1/

Comment: Worked like a charm! I guess I never thought the element on the bottom would be rendered on top. My mistake, I guess I should think of it being processed and dropped on top of everything last.


Any ideas on how to push the text out of the top of the div slightly?